# jquery replace string with backslash to space

Tags: jquery, string, replace

```
 data[i].replace('\\10.10.12\AxDocuments\', '')
```

I am trying to replacing this string to space but I don't make it

Comment: Just replace all single slash by double slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslashes have to be escaped. If you are looking for a string that starts with 2 backslashes, use the following:

```
data[i].replace('\\\\10.10.12\\AxDocuments\\', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
 var str = 'a/b/c';

    var replaced = str.replace('\', ' ');

    var replaced = str.replace(/ /g, ' ');
```